# Remove xml tags using Python 3.5

Tags: python, xml, document

So I'm new using python.  I'm trying to remove an xml tag from an xml document.  Trying to remove ALL of `<tag2>` and `</tag2>` tags, but keep the "foo" and "bar".  Suggestions?  Trying to avoid lxml

```
  <entry name="xml">
    <tag>
      <tag2>foo</tag2>
    </tag>
    <tag3>
      <tag2>bar</tag2>
    </tag3>
    <tag4>
      <tag2>foo</tag2>
    </tag4>
    <tag5>
      <tag2>bar</tag2>
    </tag5>
  </entry>
```

EDIT:
Here's what I need the output to be

```
entry name="xml">
    <tag>
      foo
    </tag>
    <tag3>
      bar
    </tag3>
    <tag4>
      foo
    </tag4>
    <tag5>
      bar
    </tag5>
  </entry>
```

Comment: What would be the desired output in this case? And what have you tried? Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? Do you know about https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.html

Comment: You mean parse and process an XML document without using an XML parser? You won't get very far doing that...

Comment: You don't need to *remove* the tags, you just need to parse it and *read* the nodes' text values...

Comment: I tried utilizing etree, but again I'm fairly new using python.  This request is simple enough using sed, but I'm trying to gain better knowledge using python for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate over the element tree with xml. This creates a list of all the tags with text in them.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('x.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

text = []
for child in tree.iter():
    if '\n' not in child.text:
        text.append(child.text)
```

---

Or a simpler statement from David Zemens

```
text = [child.text for child in tree.iter() if not child.text.strip() == '']
```

Comment: `text = [child.text for child in tree.iter() if not child.text.strip() = '']`?

Comment: Ah, that's much better. Thanks @DavidZemens !